# Intuition for why variance of sample means depends only on sample size?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

The variance of sample means is given by $\sigma ^2 / n$ where $n$ is the sample size.

Interestingly, this does not seem to depend on the size of the population — one would expect that the variance would be governed by some fraction of sample size to population size, but this is not the case.

Is there any intuitive reason for why this is true?

Comment: It is not true when the population size is finite and the sampling is without replacement (in the extreme case where the whole population is sampled once each, the variance of the mean is $0$).  When the sample size is a substantial proportion of the population size, then a "finite population correction factor" can be used, related to the variance of a hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: @Henry Ah In the case where the population size far exceeds that of the sample size, then it becomes readily intuitive that the variance depends on the sample size.

Comment: I was completely unaware of the difference between "population size" and "sample size". I mean, what is $\sigma^2$ in the first sentence?

Comment: @Tunococ $\sigma ^2$ is the population variance

Comment: @1110101001 I see. So, if you sample with replacement, $\sigma^2$ can be regarded as the true variance, i.e., your population is the exact representation of a discrete distribution. But if you sample without replacement, the statement does not hold, just like Henry said.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an intuitive approach.

Let $X$ be a random variable such that $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

If we have a sample of $n$ independent observations of $X$ then

$$X_1 +X_2 +X_3+ \dots +X_n \sim N(n\mu,n\sigma^2)$$

$$\text{sample mean} = \bar X = \frac{X_1 +X_2 +X_3+ \dots +X_n}{n} \sim N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n})$$

Note that $aX \sim N(a\mu,a^2\sigma^2$)

Answer (score 0):

Sample variance also i depends on population size: when you write out the formula for $\sigma^2/n$  you can see the expression for $\sigma$ will have population size. Using $N$ for population size, $\mu$ for population mean:

Sample variance is $\frac{1}{n\sqrt N}\sqrt {\sum_{j=1}^N(x_j-\mu)^2}$